# How to pass local variables from one cgi to another cgi in python

Tags: python, cgi

I have a cgi webpage that I wrote using python. This page takes input from the user and directs him to another page.
In the first page I am using local variables that I would like to send to the second page. Since these variables are not user input, they cannot be retrieved using form = cgi.FieldStorage().
So my question is, how do I retrieve variables (that were not inserted by the user) from the previous cgi page?

Comment: Could you store it in a cookie?

Comment: I don't know.. Could I?:)

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable thing to try. I dont know for sure, not my area of expertise. Other options (file, ipc etc) are more work and will have more gotchas.

Comment: Look here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm for details on cookies in CGI.

Comment: An HTML form can store [hidden](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden) values.

Comment: Yes I think that's the best way. @PM2Ring You should make it an answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. I used the file option since I had to get it done asap but I will look into the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTML form can store [hidden](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden) values.

Eg,

`<input type="hidden" name="example" value="data1">`

That input tag will not be visible on the Web page, but when the form is submitted your cgi script will receive a field named `example` that contains `data1`.